# Integrate War-Plugin for m2eclipse into Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, tomcat, m2eclipse

I set up a small web project with JSF and Maven. Now I want to deploy on a Tomcat server. Is there a possibility to automate that like a button in Eclipse that automatically deploys the project to Tomcat?

I read about a the [Maven War Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) but I couldn't find a tutorial how to integrate that into my process (eclipse/m2eclipse).

Can you link me to help or try to explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I set up a small web project with JSF and maven. Now I want to deploy on a Tomcat Server.

During development I recommend to use Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP). M2Eclipse provides support for it (assuming you have [Maven Integration for WTP](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html) installed) and your project should be recognized as a **Dynamic Web Project** runnable on a Server.

So, declare Tomcat as a **Server** (show the **Servers** view and **right-click** in it to add a Server via **New > Server**). And deploy your project to it (**right-click** on your project then **Run > Run on Server**).

There are other options like using the [`Tomcat Maven Plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/) or the generic [`Cargo Maven Plugin`](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) but I wouldn't use them for development and, since you are a Maven beginner, I don't recommend them at all. Use your IDE.

> I read about a the Maven War Plugin but I couldn't find a tutorial how to integrate that into my process.

Actually, the Maven War Plugin is only responsible of the packaging of your webapp project (it is bound automatically on the `package` phase when using a `<packaging>war<packaging>` for your project). It isn't used for deployment. But as I said, use your IDE to deploy your application during development.

Answer (score 0):

The war plugin is for generating war files, not for deploying them. What you are asking for may be provided by the [Cargo Plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin). Another interesting candidate for you could be the [jetty-maven-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin).